# No sound in headphones (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, audio, drivers, windows-10, headphones

I recently upgraded my Asus P500CA laptop from Windows 7 to Windows 10. The upgrade process went fine, however, no sound is coming through my headphones even though there is sound coming out from the laptop's built-in speakers.

Symptoms/what I already tried:

- I hear sound from my computer, but when I plug in the headphones, the sound stops which means they get detected in a way.
- The headphones don't appear in Sound (control panel) so I'm not able to select them.

  - I have enabled "Show disabled devices" in Sound, however, nothing changes.
- I have updated all sound-related drivers in Device Manager (if I try to update driver software again, Windows says it is already up-to-date).
- I have tried 2 different sets of headphones and neither of them work.
- I have a dual-boot, and from the other OS, I can hear the sound coming out of the headphones, which means the jack isn't damaged in any way.

I really don't know what the problem could be - I tried searching online but without any success. Does anybody know what else I could try?

Answer (score 5):

Update your Realtek audio driver.

> [After upgrading to Windows 10 - There is no sound from headphone](http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013930/)
>
> Open Settings——Update & security——Run Windows Update (there has
>   Realtek audio driver  in detail, download and install)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is nothing under Run Windows Update, but I'm going to try the alternative manual method that they suggest on that page.

Comment: Ok, so actually I don't really know how exactly I solved it, but what I found out is that in settings, I had a stuck update at 45% so I removed it and started the update process again (how-to guide http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-stuck-downloading-updates). It didn't help so I went to drivers settings and reverted to previous version of driver which also didn't help immediately but today I booted up and everything works as expected - I get sound in my headphones! So I guess it was something with updates ...

Comment: For me, the Realtek audio driver is ever-present when I refresh the update list, and always gets installed (I have it visible a few times in the "installed updates" section). Any ideas?

Comment: mine resolved by update windows 10 details here: https://superuser.com/a/1537132/165591